# Google Glass Not Found in ADB on OSX

Tags: android, macos, google-glass

So I haven't found an answer to this on Stack Overflow for OSX, just Windows, but I'm trying to run the Hello World Google Glass project from Android Studio 8.4, but the physical Glass device isn't coming up in my list of devices. I've tried adb kill-server and adb start-server, turning debug off and back on from Glass, and restarting the device. Anyone have any other suggestions to get this working?

Edit: Alright, I'm not sure what that was about, but after restarting my machine for a second time it came up.